# ¿mi modulo javascript no es posible importarlo a index.js?

Tags: javascript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Uso una página `index.php` y en ella con `<script src="inicio.js"></script>`, linkeo  a mi `inicio.js`, y en `inicio.js` importo una función que esta como módulo  en otro archivo `estilooscuro.js`: imagen1;

Luego en imagen 2 esta la importación a `inicio.js`, me sale el siguiente error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'modoDark'. import call expects exactly one argument.
```

Me sale el error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

pero ya subí la importación a la primera línea de código.

¿Por qué sucede esto?

Comment: Y donde están las imagenes? De igual manera recuerda realizar el [tour] y revisar [ask]. Es preferible poner código como texto y no como imagen. Bienvenido a [es.so]

Comment: añadi las imagenes

Comment: Que complicado va a ser ayudarte así. Te indiqué que es preferible el código en forma de texto, no en imagen, y también es muy importante el contexto. Si pones una imagen con una línea de código es muy complicado ayudarte. Agrega toda la información relevante, que se vea el contexto, donde lo usas?, como lo usas?, donde esta ubicado el index.php?, donde están ubicados los demás archivos?, como los incluyes? etc, etc etc... Si juegas a ocultar información va a ser complicado.

Comment: si disculpe ya lo solucione , faltaba incluir type="module" en ell script de phph, gracias, es que soy nuevo en esta pagina y no soy muy experto